# Find the range of $f(x)=2|{\sin x}|-3|\cos x|$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Find the range of $f(x)=2|{\sin x}|-3|\cos x|$

My attempt is as follows:-

$$f(x)=\sqrt{13}\left(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{13}}\cdot|\sin x|-\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{13}}\cdot|\cos x|\right)$$

Let's assume $z=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{13}}\cdot|\sin x|-\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{13}}\cdot|\cos x|$

$$f(x)=\sqrt{13}z$$

Let's find the range of $z^2$

$$z^2=\dfrac{4}{13}\cdot\sin^2x+\dfrac{9}{13}\cdot\cos^2x-\dfrac{6}
{13}|\sin2x|$$
$$z^2=1-\dfrac{6}{13}\cdot|\sin2x|$$

$$z^2=1-\dfrac{6}{13}\cdot[0,1]$$
$$z^2=1-\left[0,\dfrac{6}{13}\right]$$
$$z^2=\left[\dfrac{7}{13},1\right]$$

As $0$ is not there in the range of $z^2$, so we can say $z\in \left[-1,-\dfrac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{13}}\right]\cup \left[\dfrac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{13}},1\right]$

Hence $y \in \sqrt{13}\left(\left[-1,-\dfrac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{13}}\right]\cup \left[\dfrac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{13}},1\right]\right)$

$$y\in[-\sqrt{13},-\sqrt{7}]\cup[\sqrt{7},\sqrt{13}]$$

But actual answer is $[-3,2]$

Comment: Is it hard to see the range of $a|\sin x| - b|\cos x|$ is $[-b,a]$ ? (when $a,b\gt 0$)

Comment: @pooja, how it is obvious tell me, can you give some analysis.

Comment: Hey you can just eyeball it. I'm afraid explaining it only makes it look complex. But I'll try..

Comment: First notice that the second term "$-b|\cos x|$" is never positive. So "$a$" is an upper bound of $f(x)$. That is $f(x)$ cannot exceed "$a$". With me so far?

Comment: you are correct, but we don't solve questions in this way, can you give some mathematical way to solve the problem

Comment: Eyeball is the way I used. I can see how you're not impressed haha

Comment: actually I recommend the mathematical way as if someone complicates this expression a bit more, then it is difficult to "eyeball", so it is always good to use some mathematical way as it can work for more complex expressions as well.

Comment: I understand. For example one cannot eyeball  $2|\sin x| \color{red}{+}3|\cos x|$.  Because the upper/lower bounds are not obvious. Though I felt  your original expression was designd to eyeball :)

Answer (score 1):

For $0\le x\le\dfrac\pi2,$

$$f(x)=\sqrt{2^2+3^2}\sin\left(x-\arcsin\dfrac3{\sqrt{2^2+3^2}}\right)$$

Now $0\le x\le\dfrac\pi2\implies-\arcsin\dfrac3{\sqrt{2^2+3^2}}\le x-\arcsin\dfrac3{\sqrt{2^2+3^2}}\le\dfrac\pi2-\arcsin\dfrac3{\sqrt{2^2+3^2}}$

Again,
$\dfrac\pi2-\arcsin\dfrac3{\sqrt{2^2+3^2}}=\arccos\dfrac3{\sqrt{2^2+3^2}}=\arcsin\dfrac2{\sqrt{13}}$

As $\sin$ is increasing in $\left[-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right]$

$$\implies-\dfrac3{\sqrt{2^2+3^2}}\le\sin\left(x-\arcsin\dfrac3{\sqrt{2^2+3^2}}\right)\le\dfrac2{\sqrt{13}}$$

Observe that $$f(\pi+x)=f(x)=f(\pi-x)$$

which cover $\left[\pi,\pi+\dfrac\pi2\right]$ and $\left[\dfrac\pi2,\pi\right]$

Comment: see you only took the range of $x$ as $0<=x<=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and didn't care about other values of $x$, why is it so?

Comment: @user3290550,  We need to check for $$[0,2\pi]$$ Observe that $$f(\pi+x)=f(x)=f(\pi-x)=f(2\pi-x)$$

which cover $$\left[\pi,\pi+\dfrac\pi2\right]$$ and $$\left[\dfrac\pi2,\pi\right]$$  and $$[3\pi/2,2\pi]$$

Comment: ok got it , thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your domain is 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. That's where sine and cosine are positive. So at those points you are limited to the range of $[-3,2]$.

Unless you are given additional instructions, you are way over complicating it.

Comment: bro, here $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ can be negative also, so your answer is totally incorrect.

Comment: Because it covers it regardless, since their inverses are positive due to absolute values. Look at poojas example. Again, you are over complicating it, we have all been there.